# Header files that will be linked for arm-none-eabi-gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, stm32, linux-mint

I have recently been experimenting with different micro controller of the AVR/PIC and MSP430 family and on top of that I switched from Windows to Linux to do the software work without using any GUI/IDE. I am now looking to learn the STM32 Family controllers.

I want to use the ARM GCC tool-chain for it. Follow is the version that I have installed.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:4.9.3+svn231177-1) 4.9.3 20150529 (prerelease)
```

I have downloaded the Standard peripheral library provided by the Semiconductor company from [here(Standard Peripheral Library)](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32054.html). While going through all the folders present in it, I didn't find any standard library like stdio.h or stdint.h .

Will it use the gcc's library and convert and generate the .out file for the STM? Or Do I have to mention explicitly that I am generating the code for the micro-controller and not for the host system if I am including the standard library?

And any reference for using STM32 and using arm-none-eabi-gcc will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`stdio.h` is dependent on the operating system, and works with files. Most microcontrollers do not have any kind of standard library. As for `stdint.h`, I'd say that the tool chain is using an older version of the c standard. [`stdint.h` did not exist until c99.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

Comment: Of course most of the toolchains includes the std library as well.

Comment: @PeterJ I'm 90% sure the AVR tool chain for the arduino doesn't include anything like `stdio.h` or `stdint.h`

Comment: you are wrong. I think that you just do not understand what the standard library actually is. I use it all the time both on stm & avr uCs

Answer (score 0):

1. ***.h*** files are not linked anyway. Only object and library files (which are sets of of the objects files) link. ***.h*** files should only contain declarations and definitions but not the actual data or functions.
2. SPL (I assume that you use STM uC) is an outdated library and should not be used. Use HAL library instead. SPL & HAL are libraries helping programmers access low level peripheral, without need of direct bare register access. Thew easiest way to get the HAL is to use CubeMX software.
3. standard library is usually a part of your toolchain. Actually I have not found any wihout it (I use arm &avr micros)

Because you are beginner install openstm32 software (eclipse + plugins + toolchain) and you will get all you need. To avoid problems new project generate using CubeMX and import them to the openstm32